# Properly changing Ajax MultiHandle Slider parameters on postbacks

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ajax, slider, handle

In VS2010 I have VB.NET codebehind aspx pages and I'm using Ajax multihandleslider extensions to filter search results on numerical values.

Fistly, the multihandle sliders don't display in the designer... I have to remove the slider targets tag:

   
   

In order to make it display in the designer... this isn't so much a big issue but an annoyance.

I am displaying items in a given category.
So I get the max and min prices for all items in that category and assign the sliderextension max/min values appropriately.

This works fine until...
I change the item category and go get a new max/min value for the slider control.
I set the max/min values, then I set the target textbox values each to the corresponding max/min values.

The slider handles don't repaint (or init?) properly
Like say for example my initial min/max is 1/100
if I do a full postback and change the max value to 1000 then the slider bar (correctly) stays the same size but the handle appears WAYYYY to the right off the page and I have to scroll to it.
When I click it, it shoots back onto the slider bar.

I'm pulling my hair out... why do the slider handles only appear properly when I first set the min/max values?

Comment: very few views... do I need to be more descriptive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this response is to little to late, but for anyone who have this problem the solution is to reset/clear MultiHandleSliderExtender ClientState.

For the above example:

```
ajctMultiHandleSliderExtender.ClientState = "0";
```

or

```
ajctMultiHandleSliderExtender.ClientState = "1,1000";
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't resolved the intial problem with the AJAX sliders but I used the Telerik sliders and they do not have this issue.
Just FYI for any readers who stumble upon this.